# Soft bodies going through each other?

Tags: error, soft-body

I'm making a simulation in blender where a lot of objects fall in a plane and they work fine, it's just that when I join them and I check the "Soft body Self Collision" option some of them bounce but some of them go through each other as if nothing was changed. I have to say, though, that some of the ones that do this are copies of themselves. Maybe that affects.

Anyways, I'll send the .blend file. The one I'm sending has no collision between soft bodies.[The file.](http://www.mediafire.com/file/aqgxafzljct0qlf/Jello.blend)
Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on Collision for each of the softbody object so they interact with each other.
[image]

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe it was so simple it flew above me. That was very helpful, Mike! Thanks!